# unit test a function calling RenderPartialViewToString on MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I want to unit test a controller action that uses RenderPartialViewToString to render a Json.
I use NSubstitute as framework for test. the problem here is because of the use ControllerContext witch is not available in test envoironnement.

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

            ViewData.Model = model;
            ViewBag.RepositoryFactory = this.RepositoryFactory;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }

        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper class that returns needed data while using ControllerContext internally and substitute it with your testing framework.

Also, for this kinds of things there are testing frameworks that allow substituting statics, like [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/)